# Chromecast Android - Video title MediaMetaData key has vanished

Tags: android, chromecast

I used to get the Video title from an Android application using the getRemoteMediaInformation() from CastCompanionLibrary, I really need the title of the video that is being streamed, but until yesterday, the MediaMetaData doesn't have the MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE anymore! Does anybody know another solution??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your question to mention that it is really the YouTube app that you are trying to interact with and that is the critical part of the issue that is not mentioned in your post (based on your post in the cast Developer G+ Community). Even if you find a new way to get the title from the YT running app on chromecast, as long as it is not part an official apis or specs, that is bound to be broken in some future updates and you'll be facing the same issue again. So I suggest you revisit your app and your approach to use the official YT Apis.